# Less verbose way of binding prototype functions to this

Tags: javascript, refactoring, prototype

I use the following paradigm of declaring classes:

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
(function () {
    myNamespace.MyClass = function () {
        if (!(this instanceof myNamespace.MyClass)) {
            return new myNamespace.MyClass();
        }

        this.field = 17;

        this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
        this.bar = this.bar.bind(this);
    };

    myNamespace.MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){
        console.log(this.field + 1);
    };

    myNamespace.MyClass.prototype.bar = function(){
        console.log(this.field + 2);
    };
})();
```

I use `prototype` to avoid redeclaring the object methods on every instantiation, and to make the code a bit cleaner - separating the class fields from its logic.
I call `bind` on every method, to avoid nasty bugs where `this` points the wrong way inside the methods.

It works, but it is error prone - I have to remember to call `bind` on each method, and it is too verbose, especially when there are more than two methods.

**Is there a cleaner* way to declare these kind of functions (bound to their type's `this`, and declared on the `prototype`)?**

*I know "clean" is not well defined - A simple metric would be code length.

Comment: binding is bad when you have perfectly re-usable generic methods. you can give the function a name to avoid "prototype." everywhere, just publish the constructor to your namespace and use local path within the wrapper.

Comment: "I call bind on every method, to avoid nasty bugs" that's extremely excessive. It's better to understand how JavaScript works and avoid the bugs intentionally than try to "fix" the language, avoiding a whole set of features in the process.

Comment: Those nasty bugs happen quite a lot, especially if you use knockoutjs like I do. Consider what is described [here](http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2013/09/26/function-dot-prototype-dot-bind-edge-cases/).

Comment: You should be careful and knowledgeable about when your methods are being called with another context. The best solution is not to have bound methods on every instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be binding your methods like that - you're creating new functions on every instance, when you really should just have the methods on the prototype to save memory. If you create 100 instances, you are making 200 new functions! A simple pattern like this is more common and will work fine:

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
myNamespace.MyClass = (function() {
  function MyClass() {
    this.field = 17;
  }

  MyClass.prototype = {
    constructor: MyClass,
    foo: function() {
      console.log(this.field + 1);
    },
    bar: function(){
      console.log(this.field + 2);
    }
  };

  return MyClass;
}());
```

Comment: Please see the question I asked @Jivings in his answer - Doesn't this solution lose the binding to the instance?

Comment: Yes, that's the point, you do not want to do that. Like I said, bind creates a new function, so you are making 2 new functions on every instance which have to be stored in memory. This is inefficient and just bad practice - in fact it completely bypasses the purpose of using prototypes at all. Just use `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { asdf.foo(); });`. If you're doing this often, then abstract it into a helper function. Binding is not meant to be some kind of universal tool to use on every class method.

Answer (score 1):

Attach to your namespace after declaring your class:

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
(function () {
    var MyClass = function () {
        this.field = 17;
    };

    MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){
        console.log(this.field + 1);
    };

    MyClass.prototype.bar = function(){
        console.log(this.field + 2);
    };
    this.MyClass = MyClass;

}).call(myNamespace);
```

By calling the IIFE with the namespace as scope you can keep the module clean by exposing the class on the `this` object.

Comment: Suppose somewhere else, I instantiate: `var asdf = new myNamespace.MyClass()` and then pass `asdf.foo` to: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", asdf.foo)`, will this point at `asdf`? How will it work without calling `bind`?

Comment: You call bind when you add the event listener with whatever scope you want it to maintain (or use an anonymous function). You don't bind when you create the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can compact some of the prototype definitions in a single assignment and pass your namespace into function call.

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
(function () {
    function MyClass() { 
        this.field = 17;
    };

    MyClass.prototype = {
        foo: function () {
            console.log(this.field + 1);
        },

        bar: function () {
            console.log(this.field + 2);
        }
    };
})(myNamespace);
```